# Null Pointer Exception only on 4.0.3 (Ice Cream Sandwich) devices, caused by FragmentManager.Impl.removeFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, fragmentmanager

My app runs fine on all versions of android above 4.0.3, but when I run it on 4.0.3 it force closes due to a Null Pointer Exception when it removes a fragment. The stack trace doesn't point to any specific line of code, and I have no idea why it would return null when removing a fragment just on 4.0.3 devices.

Stack trace

```
09-20 13:50:17.541: E/AndroidRuntime(2152): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-20 13:50:17.541: E/AndroidRuntime(2152): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fsck.k9/com.fsck.k9.activity.MessageList}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-20 13:50:17.541: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
09-20 13:50:17.541: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
09-20 13:50:17.541: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
09-20 13:50:17.541: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
09-20 13:50:17.541: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-20 13:50:17.541: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-20 13:50:17.541: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-20 13:50:17.541: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-20 13:50:17.541: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-20 13:50:17.541: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-20 13:50:17.541: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-20 13:50:17.541: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-20 13:50:17.541: E/AndroidRuntime(2152): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-20 13:50:17.541: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeFragment(FragmentManager.java:1117)
09-20 13:50:17.541: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:592)
09-20 13:50:17.541: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1382)
09-20 13:50:17.541: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4474)
09-20 13:50:17.541: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1929)
09-20 13:50:17.541: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     ... 11 more
```

Places in my code where I remove a fragment (Note: the log outputs "remove fragment: yes" right before it crashes, so I think removeFragments() actually does work, and it might be the other two methods.

```
private void removeFragments() {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);

        boolean hasMessageListFragment = (mMessageListFragment != null);

        if (!hasMessageListFragment) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            mMessageListFragment = MessageListFragment.newInstance(mSearch,
                    false, (K9.isThreadedViewEnabled() && !mNoThreading));
            ft.remove(mMessageListFragment);
            ft.commit();

            Log.d("removed fragment?", "yes");
        }

        // Check if the fragment wasn't restarted and has a MessageReference in
        // the arguments. If
        // so, open the referenced message.
        if (!hasMessageListFragment && mMessageViewFragment == null
                && mMessageReference != null) {
            openMessage(mMessageReference);
        }
    }



private void removeMessageViewFragment() {
        if (mMessageViewFragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.remove(mMessageViewFragment);
            mMessageViewFragment = null;
            ft.commit();

            showDefaultTitleView();
        }
    }

private void removeMessageListFragment() {
    if (mMessageViewFragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.remove(mMessageListFragment);
        mMessageListFragment = null;
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

Code for the Activity is here: http://pastebin.com/VUzZeBJL

Here's the code for the MessageList fragment: http://pastebin.com/fqVqLqb8

Here's the code for the MessageView fragment (even though that never gets opened during the Activity's onCreate): http://pastebin.com/fLWDXqyX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume this is the source of your problem:

```
if (!hasMessageListFragment) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    mMessageListFragment = MessageListFragment.newInstance(mSearch,
            false, (K9.isThreadedViewEnabled() && !mNoThreading));

    // Removing a Fragment which was never added
    ft.remove(mMessageListFragment);
    ft.commit();

    Log.d("removed fragment?", "yes");
}
```

You're trying to remove a `Fragment` that has never been added to the `FragmentManager`. Why that would have *ever* worked, I don't know, but that's certainly not the correct use of `.remove()`.